# What auto-connection using white listing mean in BLE ? Does it same as directed advertising?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, whitelist

I have experimenting with Bluez 5.50 Bluetooth Stack, Here i have some confusion about procedure Auto-connection using Whitelist.

Suppose,
Device A - Advertiser
Device B - Scanner

- Add Advertisers(Device A) Bluetooth address as white list in Scanner(Device B)
- Device A will advertise with "Connectable Un-directed" adv type & default adv params
- Device B will start scanning with "Accept only PDUs from device in white list" configuration
- If B scans A's address, than explicitly B will send connection request to A(Without sending Connection create command)

What is basic difference between paired device & white listed device ?

Comment: Eh, so what dbus methods are your using? As far as I know you can't do this using Bluez?

Comment: Hey Martijn, I did not get your question for Dbus-method, I used to run DBus Daemon, Bluetooth daemon & then only Bluetoothctl / hcitool / hciconfig

Answer (score 0):

The white list can be used both when just scanning as well as when connecting.

Note that the packet exchange during advertising is this, when the central device is just scanning:

1. Advertiser sends ADV_IND.
2. Scanner sends SCAN_REQ.
3. Advertiser sends SCAN_RSP.

When the central device has a pending initiation (i.e. connection attempt) to a peripheral, the packet exchange is this:

1. Advertiser sends ADV_IND.
2. Initiator sends CONNECT_IND.
3. The connection is now established.

Note the timing between between to packets in the flow above is 150 microseconds (T_IFS), which is quite quick. If the advertiser does not detect SCAN_REQ, it does not send SCAN_RSP. If it also does not detect CONNECT_IND, it does not enter the connection state, but continue to advertise. There is a need to have a white list because the host would not be quick enough to decide if the packet should be dropped or not. Therefore the white list is implemented directly in the Bluetooth controller hardware.

A central device using the white list, will simply drop any ADV_IND having an address that cannot be found in the white list. Therefore no SCAN_REQ or CONNECT_IND is sent in this case.

"Auto-connect" therefore refers to when the initiator is constantly looking for ADV_IND packets where the sender's address is in the white list. If one is found, a CONNECT_IND is sent and the connection gets established, resulting in an "LE Connection Complete" event. Using the white list is the only way to have two or more pending connections, since otherwise you need to specify exactly one target address when initiating a connection. (Although a workaround sometimes used when the white list cannot be used, for example if it is too small to contain all desired addresses, is to let the central first perform a scan, then initiate a connection to the target addrerss, with some short timeout. This introduces latency as at least two ADV_INDs must be sent.)

Paired/Bonded device is a completely different thing. It means that both devices have stored in its database, information about the remote device, such as encryption keys, client characteristic configuration descriptor state, gatt db cache. Bonded devices are usually listed in a user interface as well.

When the white list is used when establishing connections, you can have addresses in this list of non-bonded devices. You can also have bonded devices which you do not currently want to connect to, which are then not included in the white list.

What I've written above is general BLE without any specific Bluetooth stack in mind. BlueZ might have certain conditions/flows when the white list is used.